# How to use codecs to convert from one language to a utf-8 encoded document?

Tags: python, codec

So basically I am still pretty new to Python and I have a problem where I have a document in Japanese that I am trying to convert to a utf-8 encoded document.  I don't really know what I should be getting in return when I do this.  When i run the program I currently have, it just deletes everything and leaves me with a blank utf-8 encoded document.  Here is what I have, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I'm sorry it was a typo, I fixed the original encoding.  It is Shift-jis.

```
import codecs

codecs.open("rshmn10j.txt", 'r', encoding='shift-jis')

newfile = codecs.open("rshmn10j.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8')
newfile.write(u'\ufeff')
newfile.close()
```

Comment: Well, open('w') clobbers the file it's opening. Also, it's not clear what you're trying to do -- if the document is already in utf-8 (as your first open('r') seems to indicate), then why do you need to convert it? Finally, you can use 'utf-8-sig' to get automatic BOM support instead of having to do it manually.

Comment: Do you know what codec the Japanese document is encoded in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're trying to convert a document from encoding "x" to encoding "utf8", you first have to read the document using the encoding it is encoded in.

```
import codecs

original_document_encoding = "shift-jis" # common japanese encoding.
with codecs.open("rshmn10j.txt", 'r', encoding=original_document_encoding) as in_f:
    unicode_content = in_f.read()

with codecs.open("rshmn10j.out.txt", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as out_f:
    out_f.write(unicode_content)
```

`with` is used here to auto-close the file when the block is exited.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am trying it with your method but whenever I run the program I just get the same thing that the original document has.  Do you think it is because shift-jis is the wrong codec or is it something else?  When I open the original document it does say recommend the shift-jis codec.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  When you change the encoding visually nothing should change when you open the file, only the encoding used.

Comment: I was confused as to what I should be getting but I see now that it is utf-8, thanks for the help

Comment: Can you help me with the opposite? I'm trying to take a UTF-8 file and convert it to shift-JIS. When I do I get "UnicodeEncodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't encode character u'\uff0d' in position 77: illegal multibyte sequence"